# AABBs is not what I want?

Tags: graphics, rendering, physics

If axis aligned bounding boxes axes must be aligned with the world axes, they math might not work for boxes that are rotated, thus they are not aligned with the world axes?

How do I overcome this issue?

edit:
[this](http://research.ncl.ac.uk/game/mastersdegree/gametechnologies/physicscollisiondetection1/Physics%20Tutorial%204%20-%20Collision%20Detection%201.pdf) paper says:

> Each simulated object is represented as a bounding box *aligned with the axes
> of the world*, so each collision object has a position, as well as a height, width and length.
> The axes are considered in turn, and if there is an overlap of all three axes then an intersection
> has occurred.

Did I grasp this wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can use bounding boxes aligned to any coordinate system. As long as they are all aligned to the same system you can use the AABB method.

Calculating a bounding box is relatively fast. You can do it in O(n) time on the number of the points in the object.

```
min_x = min_y = min_z = MAX_NUMBER
max_x = max_y = max_z = MIN_NUMBER
foreach(point in object):
    // transform point to desired coordinate system
    p2 = transform(point)
    if(p2.x < min_x ):
       min_x = p2.x
    if(p2.x > max_x ):
       max_x = p2.x
    if(p2.y < min_y ):
       min_y = p2.y
    if(p2.z > max_z ):
       max_z = p2.z
    if(p2.z < min_z ):
       min_z = p2.z
    if(p2.z > max_z ):
       max_z = p2.z
```

The bounding box will be given by (min_x, min_y, min_z)..(max_x, max_y, max_z).